# Android Media Recording using threads

Tags: android, media-player, media, android-mediaplayer, audio-recording

I am developing an android application that simply start and stop recording using Buttons. 
I used threads. I created three classes.. One to start recording.. one to stop recording and the main class..

The problem is that I can see the file in my mobile but it is empty and the mobile give me a msg "Unable to play video" .. I want it to work with the threads.. I dont want other methods..

This is my code 
The main class:

```
public class MediaRecorderSampleActivity extends Activity {


    Button start;
    Button stop ; 
    private MediaRecorder recorder ;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startbtn); 
        stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stopbtn); 
        start.setOnClickListener(new btnClick());
        stop.setOnClickListener(new StopbtnClick());
        }



    class btnClick implements View.OnClickListener {
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Log.i("Media", "Start Clicked...");
            Thread startThread = new Thread ( new startRe (recorder));
            Log.i("Media", "start Thread Created");
            startThread.start() ; 
             Log.i("Media", "start Recording");

                }           
    }


    class StopbtnClick implements View.OnClickListener {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
              Log.i("Media", "Stop Clicked...");
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Thread stopThread = new Thread ( new stopRecording (recorder));
              Log.i("Media", "stop Thread Created");
    stopThread.start();
    Log.i("Media", "stop Recording");
        }

  }

      }
```

The StartRecording class

```
public class startRe implements Runnable {
private MediaRecorder recorder;


startRe( MediaRecorder r ) {
    Log.i("Media", "start cons");
    this.recorder = r ; 

}
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i("Media", "IN RUN start Recording");
    startRecording();
}


public void startRecording() {
    Log.i("Media", "IN Method start Recording");
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    Log.i("Media", "create variable");
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    Log.i("Media", "1");
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    Log.i("Media", "2");
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    Log.i("Media", "3");
    recorder.setOutputFile(getFilePath());
    try{
        Log.i("Media", "prepar");
        recorder.prepare();
        Log.i("Media", "before");
        recorder.start();
        Log.i("Media", "after");
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


private String getFilePath() {
    String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
    File file = new File(filePath, "MediaRecorderSample");

    if(!file.exists())
        file.mkdirs();

    return (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp4" );
}


}
```

The stopClass

```
 public class stopRecording implements Runnable {
private MediaRecorder recorder ;

public stopRecording(MediaRecorder recorder2) {
    Log.i("Media", "Stop in Cos");
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    try {
    this.recorder = recorder2 ; }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {       
        Log.i("Media", "Stop out  Cos" + e.getMessage()) ;
        } 

}
public void run() {
    Log.i("Media", "Stop in RUN");
    stopRecording();
    Log.i("Media", "Stop out of RUN");

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a issue in how you are using the object of the `MediaRecorder`. You need to create the object in the Activity class and then pass the object to two `Runnable`..

So you need to make following changes:

Create the object in the Activity class as following code:

```
 private MediaRecorder recorder ;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startbtn); 
        stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stopbtn); 
        start.setOnClickListener(new btnClick());
        stop.setOnClickListener(new StopbtnClick());
         // Create the object in Activity so that both Runnable works on the same object...
         recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        }
```

pass the same object to both of the `Runnable` class as you already doing.

Don't create the object in the `startRecording()` method since it would create a local object and assign it to a local variable that would not be accessed from the `stopRecording` `Runnable`..

```
public void startRecording() {
    Log.i("Media", "IN Method start Recording");
    // comment this recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    Log.i("Media", "create variable");
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    Log.i("Media", "1");
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    Log.i("Media", "2");
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    Log.i("Media", "3");
    recorder.setOutputFile(getFilePath());
    try{
        Log.i("Media", "prepar");
        recorder.prepare();
        Log.i("Media", "before");
        recorder.start();
        Log.i("Media", "after");
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

try and  let us know the result...