# Freezes app when called MediaRecorder.stop()

Tags: android, video, record

I have activity with SurfaceView, i want start and stop video record in this Activity, but i want continue record video if i go to other Activity. Now i start record video(in activity 1) and go to other Activity, when i back (to activity 1) and want stop record video, my app is freezes when called `recorder.stop();` How i can fix it?

Init SurfaceView and SurfaceHolder:

```
SurfaceView cameraView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
SurfaceHolder holder = cameraView.getHolder();
holder.addCallback(this);
holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
```

Start record video:

```
 protected void startRecordVideo() {
    if (cam == null) {
        cam = Camera.open();
        try {
            cam.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    recording = true;
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setCamera(cam);
    initRecorder();
    prepareRecorder();
    try {
        cam.unlock();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    recorder.start();
}
```

Stop record video (this is app freezes):

```
 protected void stopRecordVideo() { //cam - Camera, recorder - MediaRecorder
    mc.IS_RECORD = false;
    recording = false;
    try {
        cam.lock(); 
        recorder.stop(); //app freezes in this line (i used Log)
        recorder = null;
        cam.reconnect();
        cam.release();
        cam = null;


    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

P.S. i do not use `camera.startPreview();` and `camera.stopPreview();`

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap `stopRecordVideo` inside a `Thread`, so it doesnt block the main (UI) `Thread`.

If it doesnt work, take a look at this question :

[Android Media Recording using threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14118624/android-media-recording-using-threads)

It seems you must do a little "hack"